# Migrate Java based windows service to Azure

Tags: java, azure, windows-services, serverless

I have a java based windows service, which listens on a tcp port for messages and responds. I would like to migrate it to Azure. I have the option of using a VM and installing it here, however I would prefer a serverless approach.

Note: I do not have the source code, just jar files installed using batch command leveraging wrapper.exe

What options do I have and what would be the most effective way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**: Understand How to configure WildFly.

**Step 2**: Upload data source artifacts to App Service linux.

**Step 3**: Set PostgreSQL database connection info in the Web app environment.

**Step 4**: Test the JBoss/WildFly CLI commands to configure data source.

**Step 5**: Restart the remote WildFly app server.